# CombineLatest returns wrong value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, combinelatest

I realized that the subscription returns a wrong value

```
// in ts file of a component
combineLatest([this.editSrv.getOrders(), this.route.queryParams]).subscribe(data => {
    this.orders = data[0];
    ...
})
```

with

```
// in editSrv
 getOrders(){
    // orders$: BehaviourSubject
    if(this.orders$.getValue().length > 0){
      // ordersSource = this.orders$.asObservable()
      return this.ordersSource$;
    }
    return this.http.get<any[]>("retrieve orders from api").pipe(
      map(orders => {
        this.orders$.next(orders);
        return orders;
      })
    )
  }
```

When I now remove an order with the following function in the component

```
removeOrder(order){
    let foundOrder = this.orders.find(o => o.id == order.id);
    if(foundOrder){
        const index = this.orders.indexOf(foundOrder);
        this.orders.splice(index,1);
    }
}
```

and change the `queryParams` of the current route with this function

```
cancel(){
    this.router.navigate([]); 
}
```

the `combineLatest`from above is triggered but `this.editSrv.getOrders()` returns the `orders` without the removed order although I did not call `next` but why does `getOrders()` returns now all the orders except the order I removed within the component without calling `next`? Shouldn't the source be left untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this.orders$.next(foundOrder);  after removing item;

```
if(foundOrder){
    const index = this.orders.indexOf(foundOrder);
    this.orders.splice(index,1);
    this.orders$.next(foundOrder);
}
```

and then I believe you won't need combineLatest anymore